# How does covariance matrix (P) in Kalman filter get updated in relation to measurements and state estimate?

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, system, kalman-filter

I am in the midst of implementing a Kalman filter based AHRS in C++. There's something rather strange to me in the equations of the filter.

[image]

I can't find the part where the P (covariance) matrix is actually updated to represent uncertainty of predictions.
During the "predict" step P estimate is calculated from its previous value, A and Q. From what I understand A (system matrix) and Q (covariance of noise) are constant. Then during "Correct" P is calculated from K, H and predicted P. H (observation matrix) is constant, so the only variable that affects P is K (Kalman gain). But K is calculated from predicted P, H and R (observation noise) that are either constants or the P itself. So where is the part of the equations that makes P relate to x? To me it seems like P is recursively looping here depending only on the constants and initial value of P. This doesn't make any sense. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not missing anything.

It can come as a surprise to realise that, indeed, the state error covariance matrix (P) in a linear kalman filter does not depend on the the data (z). One way to lessen the surprise is to note what the covariance is saying: it is how uncertain you should be in the estimated state, given that the models you are using (effectively A,Q and H,R) are accurate. It is not saying: this is the uncertainty. By judicious tweaking of Q and R you could change P arbitrarily. In particular you should not interpret P as a 'quality' figure, but rather look at the observation residuals. You could, for example, make P smaller by reducing R. However then the residuals would be larger compared with their computed sds.

When the observations come in at a constant rate, and always the same set of observations, P will tend to a steady state that could, in principal, be computed ahead of time.

However there is no difficulty in applying the kalman filter when you have varying times between observations and varying sets of observations at each time, for example if you have various sensor systems with different sampling periods. In this case you will see more variation in P, though again in principal this could be computed ahead of time.

Further the kalman filter can be extended (in various ways, eg the extended kalman filter and the unscented kalman filter) to handle non linear dynamics and non linear observations. In this case because the transition matrix (A) and the observation model matrix (H) have a state dependency, so too will P.